# Adding Mailchimp Contacts on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to add Mailchimp subscriber via Mailchimp api in MVC controller when form register in database.
So I use below code with api key trully wrote.

```
 public void AddContact(string email, string name, string surname, string listKey = "7f0c43ed8f")
        {
            string apiKey = "apikey comes here";
            string url = string.Format("https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{0}/members/", listKey);
            string data = "{\"email_address\": \"" + email + "\",\"status\": \"subscribed\",\"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\": \"" + name + "\",\"LNAME\": \"" + surname + "\"}}";

            WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
            myReq.Method = "POST";
            myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

            string usernamePassword = "anystr:" + apiKey;
            UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
            myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes(usernamePassword)));


            using (Stream ds = myReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
            }

            WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

But  this code works sometimes. Sometimes it gives "400 Bad Request" error and I can not find any error or solution about this problem.
I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried ?